# GCC can't find header file with -I option specified

Tags: c, gcc, include-path

I have this source file

```
//src.c
#include "include/headers/my_header.h"
```

And gcc fails with this error `include/headers/my_header.h: No such file or directory`

```
gcc my_src/src.c -Iinclude/headers
```

However, it works fine if I rewrite the source file like so:

```
//src.c
#include "my_header.h"
```

Now, I'm actually compiling a project I've inherited so I'm not trying to rewrite all of the include statements.  What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path after `-I` catenated to whatever is in the `#include` statement has to match a path in your file system. Try `-I.`, that leads to `./include/headers/my_header.h`, and presumably will let GCC find your header.